# updating angularjs libraries causes error in angular.bootstrap()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have a legacy framework that we're looking to be able to do some major updates to soon.  As part of this, we're working at bringing all our library files up to date.  During this process, we upgraded angularjs from 1.0.7 to 1.3.13.  Suddenly, we're getting a show-stopping error.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

The question is:  Why does this error happen when we upgrade to the newest library, and how am I supposed to do this now?  I will add the most relevant lines of code below, and I can add more as requested, but it's kind of complex and I'm not sure how to break it down to something easy to stick into here.

The error occurs at `angular.boostrap()`  The relevant code shows like so:

```
angular.module('app',['DataTools','ClientDataTools']);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

Main Ctrl is defined as such:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $compile) {
```

The file structure is as such:

```
load.js
run.js
dataTools.js
load / controllers.js
load / config.js
load / ClientDataTools.js
load / libraries.html
```

The automatically generated html loads up along with the js code found in `load.js`.  This first thing it does is load up `libraries.html`, which contains the imports for `run.js`, `dataTools.js`, `controllers.js`, and `ClintDataTools.js`.  The code in `load.js` then calls a function defined in run.js.  This function loads config.js and applies the settings there while going through and using jQuery to add angular tags to the form found in the automatically generated html.  It then runs the `angular.module()` and `angular.bootstrap()` commands.

`controllers.js` holds the `MainCtrl` declaration.  `config.js` is just a json string.  `dataTools.js` and `ClientDataTools.js` holds the directives used by the angular - this error still happens even when removing the directive files, so I don't think they're part of it, but they are included here out of completeness of the issue..

And no, I can't just change the html in the form in the first place.  I don't have access to it.  It's automatically generated html to which we wish to add intelligent behavior like preventative data checking.  It's an automatically generated form that we'd like to work a little more responsively.  Please don't recommend just putting the angularjs markup into the html, and please don't ask why we can't touch the original html.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* the way of declaring controller with `function MyCtrl` was deprecated - try declaring like `angular.module("app").controller("MyCtrl", function() {})`

Comment: @tymeJV - That seems to be the issue!  If you could set it as an answer I could accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Posted a quick answer, happy to help with upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of declaring controller with

```
function MyCtrl() {}
```

has been deprecated - try declaring like

```
angular.module("app").controller("MyCtrl", function() {})
```